# Chart.JS canvas gets larger every time drawn

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Working with the Chart.js library. Everytime I make an AJAX call and update the chart with the new data the chart gets larger (feels like its now resizing properly or zooming in).

I've tried to destroy the chart every time I redraw it, however I get a "Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined" error. Here's my bit of code.

```
myLine.destroy();
var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);
myLine.canvas.width = 800;
myLine.canvas.height = 500;
```

I've also tried to fix this through the CSS, but the chart gets smaller instead in the canvas

```
canvas {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 800px;
        height: auto !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't destroy `myLine` before you define it.
you don't have `canvas` defined either.

I suggest you do the following:

```
var canvas = ("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    var myLine = new Chart(canvas).Bar(barChartData);
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the Documentation of `ChartJS` and I could not find anything relates to Resizing the chart. So I tried every possible ways. But this simple thing worked out for me well. Now I have sized the `canvas` element as I prefer.

I added `height` so that it automatically adjust the width accordingly and show it in a nicer way. If u really want you could add `width` too. The `canvas` element is part of `HTML5` and allows for dynamic, scriptable rendering of 2D shapes and bitmap images. It does not allow you to input values with `px`. So ignore that and just type tha numerical value u need.

```
 <canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```